# Flyout hide himself on list view iteminvoked event

Tags: javascript, jquery, winjs

If I invoke `flyout` show function on `iteminvoked` event. The flyout automatically hide himself in fraction of second.

Here is my code

```
<div id="listView"
     class="win-selectionstylefilled"
     data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
     data-win-options="{
        itemDataSource: Teoco.ListView.data.dataSource,
        itemTemplate: select('.settingsTemplate'),
        selectionMode: 'single',
        tapBehavior: 'directSelect',
        oniteminvoked : name.ListView.selectionChanged,
        layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout }
}">
</div>
<div id="contactFlyout" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Flyout">

</div>




 Settings.SettingsModules = (new function(){
        function selectionEventHandler(evt){
            var settingsList = evt.target;
            evt.detail.itemPromise.then(function (invokedItem) {
                var flyout = document.getElementById("contactFlyout")
                flyout.winControl.show(settingsList);
            });

        }
        this.init = function(modules){
            var selectionChangeHandler = WinJS.UI.eventHandler(selectionEventHandler);
            WinJS.Namespace.define("name.ListView", {
                data: new WinJS.Binding.List(modules),
                selectionChanged:selectionChangeHandler
            });

        };
    });


     $(document).ready(function(){
        Settings.SettingsModules.init([{title : "Application"},{title : "Agent"}]);
         WinJS.UI.processAll();

     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I looked into this for you. It seems that the ListView is programmatically stealing focus on pointer up (or some other event), which causes a light dismissal of the Flyout. This is a bug, and I've [re-opened a similar issue](https://github.com/winjs/winjs/issues/986#issuecomment-120538716) on our GitHub for tracking.

In the meantime, here's a simple workaround:

```js
listview.winControl.addEventListener('iteminvoked', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () { flyout.winControl.show(e.target) }, 0);
});
```

Let me know if this solves your problem!